# Are there any other .Net implementations other than Microsoft's and Mono?

Tags: .net, cross-platform

I'm curious to know if anyone knows of any other .Net implementations of the .Net framework (any version) other than ones by Microsoft an the Mono project.

I remember reading about a version that was in Java (.Net 1.0 at the time), but I can remember what it was called now. Interesting idea though.

I have also read in a magazine that Mono can be ran on the Wii if you are a registered Wii developer and even the IPhone?

Comment: .NET implementation in Java? You mean they cloned the interfaces to be more like .NET...because someone could argue that Java is something like a father to .NET.

Comment: I remember looking at the website for it. It was a commercial product it had a headline something like ".Net everywhere".

Comment: Bobby, the design goals were very different for both Java and .NET. While you surely can learn from others in that regard I doubt you could say Java being kind of a father for .NET.

Comment: I have a feeling there was an attempt at a compiler to take C# code to JVM bytecodes, but that's not the same as .NET implemented on Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is at least one.

The free software foundation has some .NET resources known as [DotGNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/). It has a CLI implementation and are working on a webservice server.

If you are looking for interoperating with Java, there is [IKVM.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKVM) which is an implementation of Java for the .net platform.

For mono on the wii, see this [resource](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Wii).

In regards to running mono on the iPhone - look at [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/).

Comment: No argument from me... but Novel wrote mono, so they can do whatever they want with it.

Comment: "As of December 2012, the DotGNU project has been decommissioned"